# Calling instance from another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can I call the following instance of first view from another second view

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application

Comment: Could you be more precise please? "The following instance", "first view", "another second view." Who are all of them? I see just a selector (looks like a member of application delegate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applicationDidFinishLaunching is called by the application framework when your application launches. You should never be calling it.

It is part of your application's *delegate*, not of the *view*.